# Did any philosopher address the question of why it is easier to write about grammar than to write about how to write well?

Tags: philosophy-of-science

Did any philosopher address the question of why it is easier to write about grammar than to write about how to write well? I am not sure if I am very dumb to ask this question, but I am wondering why, is it just because writing well is not objective, or is it because it's not well defined, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plato’s *Phaedrus* inaugurated the philosophical discussion of literature and more generally the problem of “writing well”, which has subsequently been explored by thinkers like Nietzsche and Derrida.